# Do you guys minify node.js while deploying?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I got a weird question while I'm about to deploy my node.js code. like we create a build version for angular, do i need to generate build version before deploying?(minifying js etc.,). First time deploying node.js, please help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Minifying is used to reduce file size so users need to download less when visiting your website, since node.js is deployed on the server there is no need for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don’t need that

Minifying is used to decrease the amount of traffic, served to users. You don’t need this for a server-side code.

As an analogy, you can ask yourself "Do you minify your php or ruby code?"